# Android app recognized as gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I developed a gallery app. When I open an image from the File manager it asks me which app I want to use to view the image; what do I need to do to add my app to the list?

[image]

Also when I load a file to Google Drive I can select my app but I can't select any image, it works like always. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to your manifest file inside activity tag:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Your answer is PARTIALLY correct because I also had to handle the intent in my activity with Intent.getAction() and Intent.getType().

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Intent-Filter in MyActivity on the AndroidManifest.xml, you should obtain the data shared (the image) from the Intent.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```